# Error: Multiple commands produce '.../folly.framework'

Tags: ios, react-native, folly

After I've upgraded react-native to 0.73.4 I've encountered an issue while trying to Archive my Xcode project.

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyKeyPaaS-dvusobjtabyvaehceuotkxpwtbph/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ProjectName/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/folly.framework'
```

Update:

```
Target 'RCT-Folly.common' (project 'Pods') has create directory command with output '/Users/robert.coroianu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyKeyPaaS-dvusobjtabyvaehceuotkxpwtbph/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyKeyPaaS/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/folly.framework'

    
Target 'RCT-Folly.common-Fabric' (project 'Pods') has create directory command with output '/Users/robert.coroianu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-dvusobjtabyvaehceuotkxpwtbph/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ProjectName/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/folly.framework'
```

I want to mention that for  Dev Build the project works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Deintegrate the pods:

```
cd ios

pod deintegrate
```

Remove the Podfile and Podfile.lock:

```
rm -rf Podfile
rm -rf Podfile.lock
```

Remove the build folder:

```
rm -rf build
```

Remove the userdata:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

Update the pods:

```
pod update
```

run application:

```
cd ..
```

`yarn ios or npx react-native run-ios`

or archi from xcode, hope it will help

Comment: Didn't work for my I've tried before. I also updated my question I see that some how.. I have two RCT-Folly.  Can you help me with some clues how I can debug it?

Comment: `RCT-Folly.common`
`RCT-Folly.common-Fabric`

This can happen when you have multiple versions of the same framework installed in your project. For example, you may have installed RCT-Folly.common through CocoaPods and RCT-Folly.common-Fabric through Carthage.

to resolve this removed node-modules and remove cache and then repeat above steps, then quit xcode and reopen to run archive